# c++ Remove element from list and assign it to an object variable

Tags: c++

I have a list of vector of Data (object) and I need to iterate through the list, find the biggest vector, remove it from the list and assign it to a new variable (which is a vector of Data). I am having problems during execution (it compiles ok but then stops working). How can I get the element without destroying it so I can manipulate later?

This is the code:

```
int biggestIndex = 0, biggestValue = -1;
i = 0;
list< vector<Data> >::iterator it;
for (it = (myList).begin(); it!= (myList).end(); it++) {
    if ((*it).size() > biggerSize) {
        biggestIndex = i;
        biggestValue = basePList.size();
    }
    i++;
}
it = (myList).begin();
advance(it,biggestIndex);
vector<Data> partition = (vector<Data>) *it;
```

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE] please? Your code dosn't make sense actually (especially the `vector<Data> partition = (vector<Data>) *it;` part).

Comment: What you have posted most certainly doesn't compile ok.

Answer (score 0):

```
  auto biggest = thelist.begin();
  for (auto itr = thelist.begin() ; itr != thelist.end(); itr++) {
    if (itr->size() > biggest->size()) {
      biggest = itr;
    }
  }

  vector<int> thebiggest = *biggest;
```

This of course needs to be compiled with at least C++11 extensions enabled, so add `-std=c++11` or higher to your g++ command.

Answer (score 0):

```
auto longest = *max_element(begin(myList), 
                            end(myList), 
                            [](const vector<Data>& v1, const vector<Data>& v2)
                              {return v1.size() < v2.size();});
```